# How to store mapping tables - lucene or DB?

Tags: java, database, indexing, lucene

I want to store large mapping tables between an `id` and two text attributes.
The dataset will be up to 1 million entries and refreshed on a daily basis.

Would you rather create a `lucene` index and an index table by that id? Or create a `database` (postgres) table with id as primary key? Or even a different solution?

And why would one prefer either solution?

I only want to lookup by ID, no reverse lookup. The mapping table should be simple as that: put in an id, and get back two string attributes.

Comment: I warn you, that question is likely to attract downvotes since it reads a lot like asking about tooling and opinions, two things that are direct close reasons. I would rephrase that if I were you. Also please explain how this mapping table is exactly used in your application. Do you only lookup by ID? Or do you also do reverse lookups on text?

Comment: Added some information above. It just should be a simple key-value map (but with more than one attribute). only lookup by key/id.

Comment: What properties should the mapping engine have? From what we know, any persistable map is good enough. No need for lucene (which is a beast on texts) or a full DB.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for appears to be a [Key-value store (wikipedia article)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key-value_stores)

> Key-value (KV) stores use the associative array (also known as a map
>   or dictionary) as their fundamental data model. In this model, data is
>   represented as a collection of key-value pairs, such that each
>   possible key appears at most once in the collection.
>
> The key-value model is one of the simplest non-trivial data models,
>   and richer data models are often implemented on top of it. The
>   key-value model can be extended to an ordered model that maintains
>   keys in lexicographic order. This extension is powerful, in that it
>   can efficiently process key ranges.
>
> Key-value stores can use consistency models ranging from eventual
>   consistency to serializability. Some support ordering of keys. Some
>   maintain data in memory (RAM), while others employ solid-state drives
>   or rotating disks.

The article there also gives a rather complete list of available implementations. Unfortunately I cannot suggest you one of the implementations, as I have not used any of these in production. But I strongly believe that google is full of comparisons of key-value stores.

To answer your question, I would not go for Lucene, as it is a open source information retrieval software library, designed to implement information retrieval applications. What you are going to do is not going to hit Lucene's sweet-spots.

A classic RDBMS comes closer to your requirements. But as stated above a Key-value store would nail it.